# How to call action methods using Vue with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I recently switched from using C#.NET windows forms to using ASP.NET MVC with jquery. As a windows programmer I've basically scrapped the Model part of MVC and I just use ajax calls to pass data back and forth on my form. I'm assuming this is more of a single page application type of design although I do call other pages when the page layout completely changes.  I'm now trying to move up to a more modern library (or platform, framework, whatever). I started looking at Vue but before I make the jump I'm wondering how you do the equivalent of an ajax call using Vue? Do I use a windows api call or just call a controller method? For example if the user clicks a button how would I populate a list from data on the server?

I don't need specific details on how to do this, just the general direction or a link to a tutorial.

Also the lack of google hits on this makes me wonder if ASP.NET MVC with Vue is even a good fit.